# Is there a better restful interface for this?

Tags: rest, restful-url, restful-architecture

```
GET https://api.website.com/v1/project/employee;company-id={company-id},
title={title-id}?non-smoker={true|false}&<name1>=<value1>&<name2>=<value2>&<name3>=<value3>
```

where:
 company-id is mandatory,
 title is optional
 name/value can be any filter criteria.

Is there a better way to define the interface?

This API is not supposed to create an employee object. It is for getting an array of employee objects that belongs to a particular company and has a particular title and the other filter criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is a better way, because it depends often on the technology you use and its idioms.

However, here is two different URI designs that I like (and why)

```
#1 GET https://api.website.com/v1/project/employee/{company-id}?title={title-id}&non-smoker={true|false}&<name1>=<value1>&<name2>=<value2>&<name3>=<value3>

#2 GET https://api.website.com/v1/project/company/{company-id}/employee?title={title-id}&non-smoker={true|false}&<name1>=<value1>&<name2>=<value2>&<name3>=<value3>
```

As you can see in both example I extracted company-id from the **query string**. I prefer to add mandatory parameters in the **path info** to distinguish them. Then, in the second URI, the employee ressource is nested in the company. That way you can easily guess that you can retrieve all employee from a specific company, which is not obvious in the first example.

Comment: I kind of like the second one here. But if the title was also **mandatory**, would you add it to **path info**. That **doesn't** sound good to me.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but you are absolutely right, it doesn't sound good to me either. In fact I can't find a rule that can be applied to every case, but params like PK or FK (like company id) are good candidates for that.

Answer (score 1):

> This api is supposed to GET employee objects that satisfy the given criteria of belonging to a particular company, having particular job title and some other filter criteria.

Personally I would just design your URI as `http://acme.com/employee/?company=X&title=Y&non-smoker=Z&T=U`. I wouldn't write "in stone" that the company is mandatory: your API will be easier to change.

However, you should consider that  few "big" requests are far faster than plenty of small ones. Moreover, URI representations can be effectively cached. Therefore it is often better to have URIs based on IDs (since there are more chances that they will be asked again).
So you could get the complete employee list of a company (plus other data about the company itself) with `http://acme.com/company/X` and then filter it client-side.

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating a new employee object?  If so then a POST (create) is more appropriate.  A good clue is all the data you're pushing in the URL.  All that should be in the body of the POST object.

Comment: @Vink: If this was your intent, I second this answer. REST is a lot about understanding what "safe" and "idempotent" mean in the HTTP specification. So creating an object with GET is absolutely unRESTful. POST or PUT (which is idempotent) is the way to go.

Comment: @Aurélien, Mea Culpa! I was not clear. This api is supposed to GET employee objects that satisfy the given criteria of belonging to a particular company, having particular job title and some other filter criteria.